Degenerate Perturbation Theory of Ground State vs. Schrieffer-Wolff
Consider a Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \hat{H}_0 + t\hat{V}$ acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Here $\hat{H}_0$ is non-interacting, but the ground state is degenerate. We can denote the ground state manifold by $\mathcal{H}_{\rm GS}$. Furthermore, let's assume that the system is gapped above the ground state and then has a continuum of excited states. Meanwhile, the perturbation $\hat{V}$ introduces coupling terms and is scaled by a small parameter $t$.
Following this paper (cf. Sec. 1.2), we can use perturbation theory to define an effective Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_{\rm eff}$ within the ground state manifold. It is given by:
$$
\langle \phi |\hat{H}_{\rm eff}|\phi'\rangle = \langle \phi |\hat{H}_{0}|\phi'\rangle + \langle \phi |t\hat{V}|\phi'\rangle + \sum_{m \notin \mathcal{H}_{\rm GS}} \frac{\langle \phi |t\hat{V}|m\rangle\langle m|t\hat{V}|\phi'\rangle}{E_0 - E_m}, \qquad \text{with } |\phi\rangle, |\phi'\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_{\rm GS}
$$
From here, it seems like we should therefore be able to write an operator equation which is valid in the ground state manifold:
$$
\hat{H}_{\rm eff} = \hat{H}_{0} + t\hat{V} + t^2\sum_{m \notin \mathcal{H}_{\rm GS}} \frac{\hat{V}|m\rangle\langle m|\hat{V}}{E_0 - E_m}
\tag{A}
$$
Question 1: Before doing perturbation theory we had a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_0 + t\hat{V}$, whereas in the effective Hamiltonian we now seem to have $\hat{H}_0 + t\hat{V} + t^2[...]$; it therefore looks like we've somehow pulled a new $\mathcal{O}(t^2)$ term out of thin air. How can I justify that?

Let's now suppose $\langle \phi' |\hat{V}|\phi\rangle = 0$ in the ground state manifold, but $\langle m|\hat{V}|\phi\rangle = 0$ for $m \notin \mathcal{H}_{\rm GS}$. Then the above equation would start to make sense as the first order term would vanish -- i.e., even if there is no first order correction to the ground state energies, we
can still get a second order effect.
$$
\text{In this case: } \hat{H}_{\rm eff} = \hat{H}_{0} + t^2\sum_{m \notin \mathcal{H}_{\rm GS}} \frac{\hat{V}|m\rangle\langle m|\hat{V}}{E_0 - E_m}
$$
If $\hat{H}_{\rm eff}$ is solvable, I can just diagonalize it to get eigenstates within the ground state manifold $|i\rangle$ with (now) slightly different energies $E_{0i} \approx E_0$. In particular $E_{0i} \ll E_m$ for all higher states since the ground manifold is gapped. Let's say I now want to calculate transition rates between these states due to coupling with the continuum of excited states above the (gapped) ground manifold. I suppose I could then do a Fermi's Golden Rule type calculation to get transition rates $\gamma_{i \to f}$.
Question 2: For such a FGR calculation, what should I use as my perturbation operator? My thought is that the perturbation Hamiltonian coupling the eigenstates $|i\rangle$ to the continuum is just the original perturbation $t\hat{V}$. But how can I justify this? Or if that's not correct, what should I use instead?

An alternative perturbation theory approach to get an effective Hamiltonian is the Schrieffer-Wolff method. Here, I use a unitary transformation $e^{t\hat{S}}$ which perturbatively diagonalizes the Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \hat{H}_0 + t\hat{V}$. Note that the unitary goes to the identity as $t \to 0$. The effective SW Hamiltonian is
$$
\hat{H}_{\rm eff, SW} = e^{t\hat{S}} \hat{H} e^{-t\hat{S}} = \hat{H}_0 + t\hat{V} + t[\hat{S}, \hat{H}_0] + t^2[\hat{S}, \hat{V}] + \frac{t^2}{2}[\hat{S}, [\hat{S}, \hat{H}_0]] + \cdots
$$
In the SW method, we typically cancel the first order terms by choosing the generator $\hat{S}$ such that $\hat{V} + [\hat{S}, \hat{H}_0] = 0$. Then what's left is, to second order:
$$
\hat{H}_{\rm eff, SW} = \hat{H}_0 +  \frac{t^2}{2}[\hat{S}, \hat{V}]
$$
Question 3: In this case, we see that $\hat{H}_{\rm eff, SW}$ has no $\mathcal{O}(t)$ terms! So how is this SW effective Hamiltonian different from the above "perturbation theory" effective Hamiltonian in Eq. (A)? In particular the latter has a term proportional to $t$, whereas the former does not. How should I think about the differences between these two?

Maybe don't use $t$ to stand for your "small parameter." Seems confusing since time is usually denoted by $t$.

The paper you cite seems to already answer at least some of the questions you are asking. They provide the equation: $PH_{eff}P = PH_0P + PVP + PVQ\frac{1}{E-QH_0Q}QVP$, which is not what you wrote in your Eq. (A).

I feel bad for doing self advertisement but I address this in a recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.10656. When you do SW you can also include block diagonal components of V. For some reason this term is often assumed not to be present. But if you include it, the two results are reconciled
